# Refresh Value in NSMutableDictionary using ViewWillAppear

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

See this code:

```
    int i = years;
 NSLog(@"Years i: %i",i);
 NSString *syears= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]; 

 menuList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 

 [menuList addObject:[NSMutableDictionary 
       dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
       @"years", kLeftKey, 
       syears, kRightKey, nil, kControllerKey, nil]];
```

The above is an extract from `ViewWillAppear`.  When I switch between tabs `ViewWillAppear` is doing it's job and the data is updating down as far as `NSString *syears= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];`  but after that my array doesn't get updated with the latest value of syears. I tried using `setObject` and `setValue` but these don't work with `NSMutableArray`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Keys and values in `NSDictionary` need to be non-`nil` `NSObject`s. So you've definitely got an issue with a `nil` in there, and there may be a question about `kLeftKey` et al, for which you haven't shown the definitions.

More generally, it would help to know what you are doing with `menuList` and what you mean by "my array doesn't get updated". Are you trying to display it? Using it as a data source somewhere? You are creating the array anew here -- could a previous reference be being left around and displayed?